# Put the last date of the file versioned with Git

Tags: compiling, windows, revision-control, git

I have many TeX files for to get their PDFs versions and I put a date in each of them like as *last updated* data.

```
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
updated \today
```

But this is tricky, because every time that I compile them, this date would change in function of the day that I do it. So, because I track my changes with Git I want to change the `\today` command with the last date when the file was commited; and a file could be commited or not in the last change.

I use TeXLive distribution on Windows and I have a `make.bat` file for an automatic compilation of the files:

```
@echo off
for %%G in ("*.tex") DO (call :singlefile "%%G")
goto :eof

:singlefile
echo compiling %1
latexmk -xelatex -bibtex- -silent -auxdir=output -outdir=output %1
goto :eof
```

My Git version: 1.9.4.msysgit.0

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you heard of the [`gitinfo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo) package and its recent successor, [`gitinfo2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo2)? I don't know the specifics, but I'd say they're your best chance.

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: I believe gitinfo2 will do what you want, and more. However, it gives you access to commit dates, rather than individual file dates. [Full disclosure: I am the author and current maintainer]

Comment: BTW, `gitinfo` is now deprecated for new work, and is kept on CTAN and in the distributions so that existing documents don't break. If you decide to use this, please use `gitinfo2`.

Answer (score 5):

After checking documentation of `gitinfo2` package, I got this file/directory structure:

- main directory

  - file.tex
  - other.tex
  - gitexinfo.sty (copied from `gitinfo2`)
  - gitinfo2.sty (copied from `gitinfo2`)
  - make.bat

Then I updated my `make.bat` file for to get the `gitHeadInfo.gin` file. With this change I avoid to use git hooks; I had just to reformat it for batch-Windows style:

```
@echo off

set GitInfoFormat=\usepackage[%%^
        shash^={%%h},^
        lhash^={%%H},^
        authname^={%%an},^
        authemail^={%%ae},^
        authsdate^={%%ad},^
        authidate^={%%ai},^
        authudate^={%%at},^
        commname^={%%an},^
        commemail^={%%ae},^
        commsdate^={%%ad},^
        commidate^={%%ai},^
        commudate^={%%at},^
        refnames^={%%d},^
        firsttagdescribe^={$FIRSTTAG},^
        reltag^={$RELTAG}^
    ]{gitexinfo}

git --no-pager log -1 --date=short --pretty=format:"%GitInfoFormat%" HEAD > .git/gitHeadInfo.gin

for %%G in ("*.tex") DO (call :singlefile "%%G")
goto :eof

:singlefile
echo compiling %1
latexmk -xelatex -bibtex- -silent -auxdir=output -outdir=output %1
goto :eof
```

At this point, `$FIRSTTAG` and `$RELTAG` does not work with this, but I do not need them currently. And I think I can survive using the commit dates.

With this environment, the workflow would be:

1. Do changes.
2. Testing results with `make.bat`.
3. Commit changes.
4. Compile with `make.bat`.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks reasonable, though it may be a bit brittle. I'm sure you've already thought over the cases where the working copy has uncommitted changes, and also what happens when you start adding folder structure. That's why I think I'd recommend using the hooks.

Comment: Currently, my workflow is 1) Do changes, 2) Testing results with `make.bat`, 3) Commit changes, 4) Compile with `make.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that runs with `gitinfo2`. Hence I really like `gitinfo2`; the hooks mechanism proposed never satisfied me.

Lie Phersho, I ended up doing Makefile and shell scripts, but they weren't properly handled by my LaTeX editor and were not working on all platforms.

Finally, I ended up writing a kind of plugin for `latexmk`. `latexmk` is a nice tool that handles nicely the multiple compilations runs of LaTeX as well as the bibliographies. And last but not least, `latexmk` is working with most LaTeX editors.

This plugin is named `gitinfo2-latexmk` and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/rbarazzutti/gitinfo2-latexmk)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that plugin.

The setup is pretty easy :

- download the *plugin* `gitinfo2.pm` (Perl module)
- add one line in your `.latexmkrc` file

Once these two small steps are done, no more boilerplate is needed. Each time you, or your LaTeX editor, run `latexmk`, the git information is ready for the package `gitinfo2`.

Comment: I'll try it later. It looks like it'll be successful